# I am trying to listen for the enter key on a login page

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web, keypress, eventhandler

This is what I have sofar.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load    
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then    
        btnlogin_Click(sender, e)
    End If
End Sub
```

It is saying that 'Keycode is not a member of system.eventargs.' Also it says that 'Keys is not declared.'

All I want is to listen for the enter key.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I've completely rewritten this answer because it sucked before.

You can't(read: shouldn't unless you are listening for an asynchronous key press [ie loading an admin screen by holding one of the F keys]) declare a Key event argument within the load function, because it'll get you nowhere. To have something 'listening' to a key press ([KeyEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), in your case, the `Enter` key, you need to specify that the event arguments need to listen to `Keys`, i.e declare `e as KeyEventArgs`. You typically add this onto things that the end-user presses the Enter key on (i.e TextBox, ComboBox, etc.). It looks like, in your code, you are trying to have the enter key run a button click function. In that case, I would suggest having a [Button.PerformClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx#Y0) rather than calling a function - in your code, it would look something like this:

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    btnLogin.PerformClick
End If
```

This way if your function name changes, but your button name doesn't, you don't have to rename everything. I hope this is more clear than my previous failed attempts.

Cheers.